# pointer data race in C

Tags: c

I am a newbie in C.

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int *p = &a;
```

when a threadA is changing the pointer `p` from pointing `a` to pointing to `b`, at the same time another threadB is reading pointer `p`, what value could threadB read? Could it be a broken value (neither 1 nor 2)?

Comment: This may depend on the platform/OS - So why risk it

Comment: Any unprotected concurrent access to a variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: By the c standard - yes, in all mainstream compilers/platforms - no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, writes to a pointer will be atomic on popular modern platforms, *if the pointer storage is aligned.*   Which it will be in your case, where the pointer is allocated on the stack.  If the pointer were stored on the heap, you would need to make sure to store it with the proper alignment.

In theory, no, it's not safe.

Comment: In practice, compiler and hardware may still reorder/eliminate writes/reads.

Comment: @2501: OP asked if the pointer could be read as a value other than the "before" or "after" value.  Which it won't be, given all the caveats I mentioned.  Yes, it could be reordered, but it won't be corrupted.

Comment: An atomic write is implemented as xchg on x86. I honestly don't know if a regular store mov is atomic (a load is though).